# Prolog definition of succ/2

Tags: prolog

I often used SWI-Prolog's feature of being able to do listing(predicate). to see how it implements some of its predicates.  I want to see exactly what it does with succ/2 because I'm using it on SWI-Prolog but I need it running with Sicstus too which doesn't have it!  I've seen what it does in the SWI manual, tried to implement it but I think it must do something extra to what I've tried.  My problem is that the listing feature just gives

%   Foreign: succ/2

Any ideas guys?

Thanks :).

Comment: The predicate is builtin and written in C. Take a look here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/git/pl.git?a=history;f=src/pl-arith.c;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SWI version is probably implemented in C for better performance. Not being written in Prolog makes it *foreign* and probably considered a *built-in*.

Here's my stab at defining SWI's *succ/2* in Prolog:

```
%%%% succ/2 to mimic the SWI Prolog built-in

succ(N0, N1) :-
    ( properly_grounded(N0) 
        ->  N1 is N0 + 1
        ; properly_grounded(N1)
        ->  N1 > 0, N0 is N1 - 1
        ; otherwise 
        -> Ctx=context(succ/2,''),
          throw(error(instantiation_error,Ctx))
       ).

properly_grounded(X):-
    (var(X) -> false
        ; 
    ( X >= 0
        -> true
        ; otherwise 
    -> Ctx = context(succ/2,X),
        E=domain_error(not_less_than_zero,X),
       throw(error(E,Ctx));otherwise
       )
   ).
```

If necessary, replace *otherwise* with *true* and *false* with *fail*.  The code was developed in SWI, the *context* part of the exceptions may have to be adjusted for SICStus.

Comment: `succ(0.0,N)` and `succ(0+0,N)` should both give a `type_error(integer, ...)`

Comment: `succ(0+I,1).` must not give an instantiation error but rather a type error.

Answer (score 0):

This question is super old, but here is a simple implementation that should have the same behavior as `succ/2` in SWI-Prolog.

```
succ(X, Y) :- integer(X), Y is X + 1, X >= 0, !.
succ(X, Y) :- integer(Y), X is Y - 1, X >= 0.
```

We need both rules, because the right-hand side of `is` must be fully instantiated, and we check that with `integer/1`.

Comment: When the condition `integer(X),var(Y) ; var(X),integer(Y) ; integer(X),integer(Y)` holds and integers are unbounded, your simple implementation works. With all erroneous corner cases, however, it fails, but it should raise the right exception for reporting the error.